# Who to get a virtual server from?

Tags: virtualhost

Sorry if this seems like a noob question for this place, but, I dont know who I should buy a virtual server from... or how to go about setting it up.

I looked at godaddys, and they seem very very bare in the features you get for 30 a month (cheap I know, but this is my first VS). The only thing I see that I may do with this server at the moment is host a few small video files that people that have bought my app can download, and a database for another app to download data from. I will also probably hosting a minimal database driven website off of it as well. Nothing fancy.

I also dont know anything about what to expect when I get it. What am I going to have to install on it, how do I actually get hosting up and running, etc... This is my first go at it. Any help woudl be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really the place for shopping questions. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: What kce said. Also, in the future, it's worth mentioning some form of currency, as "30 a month" doesn't help - 30 what? $US, $CA, $AU, $HK, GBP, R, Goats, etc.

Comment: I very much like the idea of using goats as a currency for advanced technology.

Comment: Well, after reviewing the faq, I didnt see anything in there that said I cant post questions about where to get a good server sincei m new to the game. This isnt a server for home use, its use for software that im making. So, I dont see how this isnt a relevant question. It may not be a technical/problem, but more of a theory and ask professionals their opinion so I dont make some starting mistakes that they did. I highly doubt this could be considered spam or even pointless chatter as I did get valuable information from it, and could help someone else later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the [Web Hosting Talk forum](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?f=103) for reviews and discussion about specific VPS providers. There may be additional information on the first steps (expectations, requirements, etc.) listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the posts in the web hosting talk forum as suggested by ewwhite. You'll get the idea what they are offiering.

I wouldn't use VPS in production environment as the speed of the server is dependent on other users not using the harddrive. You can also get dedicated servers for

Regardless of which you choose after payment you'll get an URL to web control panel with username/password and IP of the server with root password for SSH access. Some companies ask the OS on selecting the server, others give you access to control panel to set up the server and others give a root password for ready set server.

Comment: Becareful not to use godaddy for this anymore if you want even a basic cp, they dont supply those anymore and you have to go through SSH to install anything remotely like a cpanel without paying extra 10-20 a month for it